# TLS 1.3 with .Net Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, frameworks, .net-4.8, tls1.3, sslstream

I'm trying to setup a test enviroment to test tls 1.3 with .Net Framework 4.8

This is the client code:

```
public class Tls13Client
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string serverIP = "127.0.0.1";
        int serverPort = 8888;
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect(serverIP, serverPort);

        SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false,
            new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);
        X509Certificate2 certificate = LoadCertificate();

        try
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("localhost", new X509CertificateCollection(new[] { certificate }) , SslProtocols.Tls13, true);
            Console.WriteLine("Client authenticated with TLS 1.3");

            // Perform data exchange using the sslStream

            string messageToSend = "Hello from client!";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageToSend);
            sslStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent to server: " + messageToSend);

            // Receive the response from the server
            byte[] responseBuffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead = sslStream.Read(responseBuffer, 0, responseBuffer.Length);
            string responseData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            Console.WriteLine("Received from server: " + responseData);

            sslStream.Close();
            client.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sslStream.Dispose();
            client.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        // Add your custom server certificate validation logic here
        return true; // Accept any certificate (not recommended for production)
    }

    private static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
    {
        // Load your client certificate here
        string certificatePath = "client_certificate.pfx";
        string certificatePassword = "password";

        return new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePassword);
    }
}
```

This is the server code:

```
public class Tls13Server
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int port = 8888;
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        listener.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Server started. Waiting for incoming connections...");

        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false);
        X509Certificate2 certificate = LoadCertificate();

        try
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(certificate, false, SslProtocols.Tls13, true);
            Console.WriteLine("Server authenticated with TLS 1.3");

            // Perform data exchange using the sslStream
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                string receivedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                Console.WriteLine("Received from client: " + receivedData);

                // Echo the received message back to the client
                byte[] responseBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Server received: " + receivedData);
                sslStream.Write(responseBuffer, 0, responseBuffer.Length);
            }

            sslStream.Close();
            client.Close();


            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close...");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sslStream.Dispose();
            client.Dispose();
            listener.Stop();
        }
    }

    private static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
    {
        // Load your server certificate here
        string certificatePath = "server_certificate.pfx";
        string certificatePassword = "password";

        return new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePassword);
    }
}
```

Just by removing the Protocol.tls I can complete an handshake and write/read but as soon as i use the Protocol.tls13 i get:
Message : The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm

```
 at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface SecModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SecureCredential scc)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SecureCredential& secureCredential)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, X509Certificate2 selectedCert, Flags flags)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireServerCredentials(Byte[]& thumbPrint)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(Byte[] incoming, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Boolean renegotiation)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Boolean renegotiation)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(X509Certificate serverCertificate, Boolean clientCertificateRequired, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
   at Tls13Server.Tls13Server.Main() in C:\Tls1.3\server\Tls13Server\Program.cs:line 27
```

Enstablish tls 1.3 connection with .net framework 4.8 and write/read between client server

Comment: Please show the error as a complete stack trace of the exception as *text* rather than just a screenshot.

Comment: ok, I changed the final part of the question @jon-skeet

Comment: Which exact version and build number of Windows are you on? Side note: you are missing a bunch of `using`

Comment: The encryption mode of the certificate has to be compatible with TLS 1.3.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security?force_isolation=true.  Some encryption modes will work with only TLS 1.2, others with only TLS 1.3, and some will work with both.

Comment: What OS are you using? TLS 1.3 needs to be supported by the OS of both the client and server. See [TLS protocol version support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-#tls-protocol-version-support) and [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls)

Comment: What is the relationship between TLS negotiation and certificate? jdweng above says the cert has to be compatible with 1.3 ... however https://cheapsslsecurity.com/blog/tls-checker-how-to-check-the-tls-version-of-a-website/ says "Your SSL/TLS certificate really has no bearing on the TLS version that a server uses. The decision about which TLS protocol gets used is decided by the server based on the list of protocols supported by both parties (i.e., the server and the client attempting to connect to it)." - I don't know which is true. Or maybe both and I don't understand.